# When address is changed values gets altered

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am trying to implement a hash table in c. So i initialize my table like this:

```
int size = 4;
float filled_values = 0;


struct block{
    short int empty;
    int value;
};


void initialize(struct block **table){
    int i;
    free(*table);
    *table = malloc(size * sizeof(struct block));
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) (*table)[i].empty = 0;
    return;
}


int main(){
    struct block *table;
    table = NULL;
    initialize(&table);
}
```

everything works fine with insertions too.

```
void insert_utility(int value, struct block **table){
    int index = hash(value);
    int i = index;
    for(;; i = (i + 1) % size){
        if ((*table)[i].empty == 0){
            (*table)[i].value = value;
            (*table)[i].empty = 1;
            return;
        }
    }
}

void insert(int value, struct block **table){
    insert_utility(value, table);
    int i;
    filled_values++;
    if (filled_values / (float)size >= 0.5) double_table(table);
    return;
}
```

However when the table gets half full, I double the tables size to ensure reliablity.

```
void double_table(struct block **table){
    int i;
    int old_size = size;
    size *= 2;
    struct block **table_2;
    *table_2 = malloc(size * sizeof(struct block) * 2);

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) (*table_2)[i].empty = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < old_size; i++){
        if ((*table)[i].empty == 1){
            insert_utility((*table)[i].value, table_2);
        }
    }
    free(*table);
    table = table_2;

}
```

I debugged the code to know where the error gets a block with the value `empty` of neither 0 or 1.

It turns out that after I assign `table = table_2;` and check the values at `table` everything is fine.

Whereas after `double_table` exits in the insert function, I recheck the values of `empty` and `value` at each block, I get different results with non-sense pointer-like big values. How could've the values been altered in that way?

Comment: At the end of `double_table` you do `table = table_2;` but you must do `*table = table_2;`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie sorry. Actually the program  raises a warning `[Warning] assignment from incompatible pointer type`. And hangs at `*table_2 = malloc(size * sizeof(struct block) * 2);` of `double_table` function.

Comment: You seem to be using `0` for true and `1` for false, which is a big confusing. If you change `empty` to `full` you would be using  `0` for false and `1` for true  and you could replace `if ((*table)[i].empty == 1){` with `if ((*table)[i].full){`.

Comment: In initialize why do you free table *before* you malloc it? You are probably getting lucky and getting zero filled memory, but if there is a garbage pointer in table you could get undefined behaviour.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie do you mean `*table=*table_2`?

Comment: No, I mean what I wrote. You want to pass the new memory to the caller. `table` is just a local variable (parameter).

Comment: And your `struct block **table_2;` should be `struct block *table_2;` You are working on the _local_ `table_2` and when you are done, you pass it to the caller (as per my earlier comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand that you are working in your function on a new table, your `table_2`, and when you are done, you must pass it back to the caller, the `**table` parameter. Applying my comments gives the following function:

```
void double_table(struct block **table)
{
    int i;
    int old_size = size;
    struct block *table_2;  // this is the new table that you are working on. Just one * is enough

    size *= 2;
    table_2 = malloc(size * sizeof(struct block) * 2);

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) table_2[i].empty = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < old_size; i++){
        if ((*table)[i].empty == 1){
            insert_utility((*table)[i].value, &table_2);
        }
    }
    free(*table);      // this is correct, now do that too in the following statement
    *table = table_2;  // dereference the caller's parameter so you assign to his variable.
}
```

Comment: But now I should pass `insert_utility((*table)[i].value, &table_2);` instead of `insert_utility((*table)[i].value, table_2);`. right?

Comment: Yes. You are correct. I'll update my answer. But note that `insert_utility` doesn't need a double pointer as it doesn't change the table's base address. `struct block *table` would be sufficient.